# Different Text Quality and Output for TextPaint Tags in Android

Tags: android, canvas, text, paint, android-bitmap

I'm creating a printable tag from my Android app (it's an inspection app that allows you to print a tag on a bluetooth printer to leave on site to identify any issues you find).

I am using [`drawText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw the text on the `Canvas` and setting my paint (styles, etc.) with [`TextPaint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html).

If you take a look at the Flags available on `Paint`, which `TextPaint` inherits from, you'll see a number of flags that pertain to potential quality, like Dithering and Anti-Aliasing.

After looking over other tutorials they seem to use one of, or both of, `Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` and `Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG`.

There isn't much talk about how these options actually affect the output quality, specifically the text output quality. I know what Anti-Aliasing and Dithering do, in general, but there's no official recommendation from the Android docs on which to use for text, etc.

Is there a good resource for this?

Answer (score 5):

### DIY

Sometimes the best approach is just to try it yourself and see what you come up with.

I have a pretty basic tag I'm printing so I printed them with different combinations of flags set and font styles. To save others from examining all these options (~2 hours), I thought I would share my results.

I did find an interesting discovery: **No flags generally produces the best results, for text at least, and especially for small (10, 20) text sizes.**

*Text sizes from top to bottom are 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, respectively.*

**No Flags, Sans Serif**
[image: No Flags, Sans Serif]

**Anti-Alias, Sans Serif**
[image: Anti-Alias, Sans Serif]

**Linear Text, Sans Serif**
[image: Linear Text, Sans Serif]

**Anti-Alias, Linear Text, Sans Serif**
[image: Anti-Alias, Linear Text, Sans Serif]

**Subpixel Text, Sans Serif**
[image: Subpixel Text, Sans Serif]

**Hinting, Sans Serif**
[image: Hinting, Sans Serif]

**Dither, Sans Serif**
[image: Dither, Sans Serif]

**No Flags, Default Bold**
[image: No Flags, Default Bold]

**No Flags, Monospaced**
[image: No Flags, Monospaced]

**Anti-Alias, Linear Text, Monospaced**
[image: Anti-Alias, Linear Text, Monospaced]

**No Flags, Serif**
[image: No Flags, Serif]